# Spring Boot Metrics with Prometheus and grafana setting change for micro meter

Tags: spring-boot, grafana, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

Hi I am working on a spring boot micro service where i need metrics of each microservice.
Like how many 200 or 500 or 400 responses happen.
In prometheus i am getting total count ,i want hourly or minutes based count . how can i achieve this with prometheus or grafana
I want something like this . Last 1 Hour

/service 200 - 50 count

/service 500 - 20 count

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> In prometheus i am getting total count ,i want hourly or minutes based count

You can try prometheus query with time-range and offset

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier